# Methods of securing PDF's

Tags: security, pdf, adobe, itext

After a bit of research I've come across the following methods of securing PDF files:

- Password security
- Certificate security
- Lifecycle security

All of these except for password security seem to require software (Adobe) or even servers in the case of lifecycle security - whereas I can add Password security using iTextSharp.

Therefore I'm just looking for the best / accepted methods of providing security of PDF documents.  Are there any third party solutions?

Comment: By "security", do you mean "confidentiality" / "secrecy"? Or "integrity" (i.e. no one should change it), or authenticity (i.e. you can prove who wrote it), or access control, or prevention of malware, or or.... Or something else?

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for any methods that provide some / all of what you state - does anything as such exist?